# How to prevent PHP using too many MySQLi connections?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a messaging website, which uses a MySQL database to store the message data. However, when there are only **5 users** online at the same time, it starts failing with "`MySQLi: Cannot Connect: Too many MySQL connections`".

I have heard that my host, [HelioHost](https://www.heliohost.org/), limits the maximum MySQL connections to four, which explains my error (see [this](https://www.helionet.org/index/topic/30134-how-to-increase-max-user-connection/?hl=%2Bmysql+%2Bconnections+%2Blimit#entry136077) for details).

I want to know how I can change my scripts (which currently connect when the message form is submitted, add it to the database, then disconnect) can only use a maximum of four connections over the server.

Here's some code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("MySQL server connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Process data
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_SESSION["username"];
    $parent = $_POST["thread"];
    $content = test_content($_POST["content"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `threads_replies`(`Parent`, `Author`, `Content`) VALUES ('" . $parent . "','" . $name . "','" . $content . "')";
    $conn->query($sql) or die ("Failed MySQL query to save reply");

    echo "Reply saved. <a href=\"viewthread.php?id=" . $parent . "\"><span class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-left\"></span> Back to Thread</a>";
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
function test_content($data) {
    $data = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $data);
    return $data;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like you need to get a host that allows more connections, otherwise it's going to get difficult if your site becomes popular.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking that someone might come up with a daemon-like piece of code that connects and takes queries from other scripts, or something similar? This would eliminate the need for more connections 

Comment: "someone might come up with"? This isn't a code-writing service. If that's what you want, you should write it yourself.

Comment: You could use something like a Beanstalk queue to implement the communication between the applications and the daemon.

Comment: @Barmar I don't want someone to actually **write** the code, just to explain how it is done. I'm not that good with PHP

Comment: I just explained it. Have the daemon listen for messages on a beanstalk pipe, query the DB, then send the result back through the pipe.

Comment: However, funneling all database queries through a single connection is likely to cause problems. You won't be able to make effective use of transactions, since there's only one transaction per connection. And if the queries use `@variable` or set session variables, they'll interfere with each other.

Comment: SO is not really an appropriate site for general design questions like this. it's for you to post code that doesn't work, and ask for how to fix its specific problems.

Comment: @Barmar "Have the daemon listen for messages on a beanstalk pipe" --- that would be a problem for them: on a shared hosting it's unlikely they can spawn any long-running process.

Comment: @zerkms Very good point. I think the fundamental problem is that you're trying to run a professional-grade service with a hosting product designed for personal websites.

Comment: @zerkms I **am** allowed to spawn long-running processes.

Comment: @StellarDoor5319 then spawn your own mysql server.

Comment: @zerkms I don't have SSH though - so I can only spawn stuff using PHP. Is this possible?

Comment: Given a VPS these days costs as few as ~$5/month you're wasting your time. Check amazon lightsail or hetzner.

Answer (score 1):

Right from the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    $error = mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: $error";
    echo 'Sorry, pal, 5 already playing around...';    
    exit;// or location('wait.php');
}
# .... 
mysqli_close($link);
```

For the 5th user - he should reload the page, you can redirect him to something like **wait.php**:

```
<!-- htm, head, please add.. -->
<?php 
// no need in PHP, actually 
?>
<h3>Sorry, having too much users, will reload automatically...</h3>  

<script> 
   setTimeout(
     ()=> location.href = 
       location.href + '?t=' + (new Date()).getTime(), 
     5000 // hope 5 seconds will be enough
   );
```

So your code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    location('wait.php');
    die("MySQL server connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how this helps. All this does is establish connection to the database

Comment: I am too. It just basically tells my loyal users to go away 

Comment: @Akintunde007 It is explaining how to pick up the error

Comment: @StellarDoor5319, if you can't connect with mysqli_connect, then in your case it should be your maxlimit error, you can, ofcourse get last error, but will you care if you have no connection? result is the same, 5th user should wait until first 4 requests finished.

Comment: @2oppin Can you tell me how to do that in a separate answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a cache system which will be checked before accessing the database (and build up a connection). As an example, you don't need to read the news on the front page every time from the database, they don't change that often. So you read the news from the cache system (like some file in the file system) instead and display the data from it. And when the news entries has been changed you delete/invalidate the cache so the cache gets rebuild (once) on the next visit again.